# NodeJS Memory leaks

Tags: node.js

I've been experimenting a little with nodejs, writing a webscraper that uses proxies.
What i'm trying it to load all proxies from a proxy file. "proxies.txt" in this case.

What i don't understand is, while the webscraper is running it is giving me the following message.

```
(node:21470) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 pipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

This does not happen if i manually make an array of several proxies.

Here is the code where i load the proxies from file to array.

```
var proxy_array = [];

if (! proxy_array.length ) {
    var proxy_file = fs.readFileSync('./proxies.txt', 'utf8');
    var split = proxy_file.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
        var trimmed_proxy = split[i].replace('\r', ''); //removes the \r that gets added while i split the list i think?
        proxy_array.push(trimmed_proxy);
    }
}

console.log(proxy_array); //it does return all proxies.
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Greetings

Comment: Is that all of your code that reproduces the issue?  I don't see any place you're calling `.pipe`.  I suppose it could be internal to the Node.js libraries, but it seems weird.

Comment: Also, if this file is of any sizable length, you would benefit from processing it as a stream.  There are NPM packages for line-by-line streaming.